# Orders of the Normal Subgroups of $A_4$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

> Prove that $A_4$ has no normal subgroup of order $3.$

This is how I started:
Assume that $A_4$ has a normal subgroup of order $3$, for example $K$. 
I take the Quotient Group $A_4/K$ with $4$ distinct cosets, each of order $3$.
But I want to prove that these distinct cosets will not contain $(12)(34),(13)(24)$ and $(14)(23)$> Therefore a contradiction.
Please help, I'm really stuck!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Up to changing name to the symbols, the fact that $(234)^{-1} (123) (234) = (134)$ is enough, since it proves that any element of order $3$ is conjugated to another element which is not one of its powers.

Here is a non-elementary (but more "adaptable") proof: since the Sylow $3$-subgroups are pairwise conjugated, if there was a normal subgroup of order $3$ it would be the unique Sylow $3$-subgroup, i.e. the unique subgroup of order $3$, and this is false because $A_4$ has more than one subgroup of order $3$.

Answer (score 3):

In fact, one can show that  all normal subgroups of $A_4$ are $1$, $K_4$ (Klein four group) and $A_4$. Note that  two permutations of $S_n$ are conjugate iff they have the same type. So we can write down (by some easy calculations) all conjugate classes of $A_4$  are  the following $4 $ classes:

- type $1^4$: {(1)}
- type $2^2$: {(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)}
- type $3^1$:{(123),(142),(134),(243)} and {(132),(124),(143),(234)}

So all normal subgroups of $A_4$ are $1$, $K_4$ and $A_4$.

Answer (score -2):

$|A_4|=O(G)=12$

By Sylow subgroups

$O(G)=12=2^2×3^1$

$A_4$ has a $3$-Sylow subgroup of order $3$ and $A_4$ has $2$-Sylow subgroup of order $4$

$A_4$ has $3$-Sylow subgroup of order $3$

n=1+3r. (n|O(G))

r=0 , n=1

r=1 , n=4

A4 has 2-Sylow subgroup of order 4
n=1+4r. (n|O(G))

r=0 , n=1

2-Sylow subgroup of order 4 is unique, it is normal,
but 3-Sylow subgroup of order 3 is not unique, hence it is not normal
Therefore, A4 has normal subgroup of order 4 and not of order 3

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).